# Token StartObject in state ObjectStart would result in an invalid JSON object. Path ''."

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON

```
 {
name: 'Dashboard',
url: '/Home',
icon: 'icon-speedometer',
 },
 {
name: 'Reports',
url: '/Reports/GenerateReport',
icon: 'icon-calculator'
 },
 {
 name: 'Administration',
 url: '/adminstration',
 icon: 'icon-shield',
 children: [
  {
    name: 'Templates',
    url: '/Templates/TemplatesList',
    // icon: 'icon-settings'
  },
  {
    name: 'Rules',
    url: '/Rules/RulesList',
    // icon: 'icon-equalizer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Products',
    url: '/Products/ProductsList',
    // icon: 'icon-grid'
  },
  {
    name: 'Users',
    url: '/Users/UsersList'
  },
  {
    name: 'Clients',
    url: '/Clients/ClientsList'
  }
```

and in C# here's the model for mapping it

```
public class ParsedAccessPage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public List<ParsedAccessPageChild> children { get; set; }
}

public class ParsedAccessPageChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

and this function to parse the model to JSON

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
        jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        jw.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var page in parsedAccessPage)
        {
            jw.WriteStartObject();
            jw.WritePropertyName("name");
            jw.WriteValue(page.name);
            jw.WritePropertyName("url");
            jw.WriteValue(page.url);
            jw.WritePropertyName("icon");
            jw.WriteValue(page.icon);
            if (page.children.Count > 0)
            {
                jw.WritePropertyName("children");
                jw.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (var child in page.children)
                {
                    jw.WritePropertyName("name");
                    jw.WriteValue(child.name);
                    jw.WritePropertyName("url");
                    jw.WriteValue(child.url);
                    //jw.WriteEndArray();
                }
                jw.WriteEndObject();

            }
            jw.WriteEndObject();
            //jw.WriteEndArray();

        }
        jw.WriteEndObject();
        return sb.ToString();
```

I keep getting this error:

"Token StartObject in state ObjectStart would result in an invalid JSON object. Path ''."

I'm not sure why the 1st line in the 1st foreach keeps throwing it ... I'm trying to make the json appear as the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't `children` a property of type array of objects? Then it should look somehow like this (not tried, just following the logic):

```
if (page.children.Count > 0)
{
   jw.WritePropertyName("children");
   jw.WriteStartArray();
   foreach (var child in page.children)
   {
       jw.WriteStartObject();
       jw.WritePropertyName("name");
       jw.WriteValue(child.name);
       jw.WritePropertyName("url");
       jw.WriteValue(child.url);
       jw.WriteEndObject();
   }
   jw.WriteEndArray();
}
```

**Update:**

As the whole thing is an array, not an object (your sample json is not valid the way you have posted, as it has no enclosing marker at all), it should look like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
jw.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
jw.WriteStartArray();
foreach (var page in parsedAccessPage)
{
    jw.WriteStartObject();
    jw.WritePropertyName("name");
    jw.WriteValue(page.name);
    jw.WritePropertyName("url");
    jw.WriteValue(page.url);
    jw.WritePropertyName("icon");
    jw.WriteValue(page.icon);
    if (page.children?.Count > 0)
    {
        jw.WritePropertyName("children");
        jw.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var child in page.children)
        {
            jw.WriteStartObject();
            jw.WritePropertyName("name");
            jw.WriteValue(child.name);
            jw.WritePropertyName("url");
            jw.WriteValue(child.url);
            jw.WriteEndObject();
        }
        jw.WriteEndArray();
    }
    jw.WriteEndObject();
}
jw.WriteEndArray();
```

And this time I have tried it...

Comment: @It throws an error, I'll check it and let you know :) ... but yes it's a property of type array of objects.

Comment: I have an issue now generating the parent items ... like these 

{
name: 'Dashboard',
url: '/Home',
icon: 'icon-speedometer',
 },

Comment: Perfect .. Thank youuuuuuuuu <3